# how to fix asyncmac.sys infection

Tags: windows-xp, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

AVG anti-virus tells me that there is a virus in my asyncmac.sys. I tried to overwrite it with a copy of asyncmac.sys from another computer (making sure that it was the same version of Windows XP, but I was still nervous that I was going to break something), but when I reboot, I get the same virus warning. If I try to delete the file Windows (or somebody) automatically and immediately puts it back. I get a blue-screen death if I try to boot in safe mode. I tried to do a system restore to before I had the virus, but it tells me that it can't restore because nothing has changed.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: AVG does nothing to remove it?

Comment: as this question is abandoned i propose it be closed as a duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware

Comment: @John T: AVG tells me it can't fix it because it's a "whitelisted file" by Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, try installing Avira anti virus, and then run a full system scan, im not sure if it will damage anything, but viruses are usually damaging anyway.
It is likely that asyncmac.sys is not the only infected file.

Back up all of your important information onto a portable hard drive, or a memory stick (this may not have enough space).

**DO NOT ENTER ANY IMPORTANT DATA** such as bank details.

The best thing to do is to completely rebuild your computer.

Download Link: http://www.avira.com/en/download/index.php